# How can I import a .so module in PyPy?

Tags: python, interpreter, cpython, pypy, netcdf

I am green to PyPy, and I use PyPy1.9 to interpret my Python code.

As you know, the CPython interpreter can import a module packaged in a .so file, which is compiled from C/C++ codes.

But PyPy1.9 interpreter tell me he can not find the module in a .so file, my code is a little slow and I want to optimize the performance, help!!

Comment: It would help if you told us what you'd tried, what module you want a C version of, what platform you're on, etc. In general, while PyPy _can_ use CPython modules, it may be even faster to use PyPy-specific "mixed-mode" modules, or `ctypes`, or `CFFI` (even though `ctypes` is usually slightly _slower_ with CPython). And there are some modules that don't yet work through CPyExt (most famously `numpy` and everything that depends on it).

Comment: @abarnert, I use 'from Scientific.IO.NetCDF import NetCDFFile as Dataset' to read a NetCDF file, I am under ubuntu12.04.

Comment: The first site that came up when I searched was http://gfesuite.noaa.gov/developer/netCDFPythonInterface.html, which talks about using `Numeric` (which is an old ancestor of `numpy`), so… I won't guarantee that things will work out for you. But it's worth trying.

Comment: The next thing I found is http://code.google.com/p/netcdf4-python/ which claims to be a new implementation on top of HDF5 and netCDF instead of directly on the old netCDF interface but "modelled after Scientific.IO.NetCDF, and should be familiar to users of that module". I have no idea if that's helpful to you, but it might be a different alternative if you get stuck with this one?

Answer (score 2):

First, [CPyExt](http://morepypy.blogspot.com/2010/04/using-cpython-extension-modules-with.html) has been in PyPy since… I forget the exact version, but a couple years now, well before 1.9.

Basically, all you have to do is build and install the module, just as you do with CPython.

Make sure you do the install with PyPy, not with CPython. Besides the fact that each Python installation on your system has a separate `site-packages` directory, CPyExt requires modules to be built against the PyPy headers and libs, not the CPython ones.

If you're installing manually, just do `pypy setup.py install` instead of `python setup.py install`. If you're using `pip` or `easy_install`, the PyPy versions of those tools are usually named something like `pip_pypy` and `easy_install_pypy`.

So, if you've installed `pip`, it should be as easy as:

```
pip_pypy install foo
```

(Possibly with a `sudo`, of course.)

If you haven't [installed `pip`](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/1.3.X/installing.html), install it for PyPy the same way you would for CPython. For example:

```
curl -O https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py
pypy get-pip.py
```

If you're using a binary installer, then obviously you have to get the binary installer for PyPy-1.9. And, if there isn't one, you can't use a binary installer. (Just like if you wanted to install `foo` for CPython 2.7 on 32-bit Windows and they only had a 2.6 package or a 64-bit package.)

---

One last note: There are some packages that do not yet work with CPyExt. Most notably, `numpy` and everything that depends on it, and anything else that requires binding Fortran code. Some of these packages will check for CPython (or check for non-PyPy?) and give you an early error. Others may try to build and fail. Others may successfully build but not work in some cases (e.g., some of them fail in any program with more than 1 thread, because they try to get fancy with the GIL). But the easiest thing to do is try it and see.

Comment: @xunzhang: Well, then you have to get the binary package for PyPy. And, if there isn't one, you can't use the binary package; you have to install from source.

Answer (score -1):

For PyPy you would need to utilize something like [CFFI](https://bitbucket.org/cffi/cffi), which uses [Foreign Function Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface) to access library code (see the section on [Loading Libraries](http://cffi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#loading-libraries) for more information).

**Edit**: I stand corrected by the above answer. I'll leave this answer here though to have an alternative for accessing libraries and simply accept justified downvotes.

Comment: Not true. You _can_ do that, and you also can use `ctypes` (which works with both PyPy and CPython), but you can also just use (most) CPython extension modules.